# dynamically loading a function in a shared library causes a segmentation fault

Tags: c, vulkan, dynamic-linking, dynamic-loading, libdl

I have this simple library

`lib.h`:

```c
int lib()
```

`lib.c`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#include <dlfcn.h>

#define VK_NO_PROTOTYPES
#include <vulkan/vulkan.h>

PFN_vkGetInstanceProcAddr vkGetInstanceProcAddr;
PFN_vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties;

int lib()
{
    void *lib = dlopen("libvulkan.so.1", RTLD_NOW);
    vkGetInstanceProcAddr = dlsym(lib, "vkGetInstanceProcAddr");

    vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties = (PFN_vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties)vkGetInstanceProcAddr(NULL, "vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties");
    uint32_t count;
    vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties(&count, NULL);
    printf("%d\n", count);

    return 0;
}
```

I compile it to a shared library using

```makefile
libabc.so: lib.o
    $(CC) -shared -o $@ $^ -ldl

lib.o: lib.c lib.h
    $(CC) -fPIC -g -Wall -c -o $@ $<
```

But when I use this library in an application I get a segfault when `vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties` is called on line 18.

What's more, if I change the name `vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties` to something else, say `test`, then everything works just fine and (in my system) `6` is printed. It also works if I don't use a dynamic library at all, i.e. I compile `lib.c` together with `main.c` directly without `-fPIC`.

What is causing this and how do I resolve it?

Comment: When you dynamically link the functions, what is the value of `vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties` after getting the function pointer from the vulkan DLL?

Comment: GDB reports `(PFN_vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties) 0x7ffff7fc4050 <vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties>`

Comment: What about static compilation? Just curious to see if there's a significant difference in address.

Comment: `(PFN_vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties) 0x7ffff7da1810 <vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that these two definitions:

```
PFN_vkGetInstanceProcAddr vkGetInstanceProcAddr;
PFN_vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties;
```

define *global* symbols named `vkGetInstanceProcAddr` and `vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties` in `lib.so`.

These definitions *override* the ones inside `libvulkan`, and so the `vkGetInstanceProcAddr(NULL, "vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties");` call returns the definition *inside* `lib.so`, instead of the intended one inside `libvulcan.so.1`. And that symbol is not callable (is in the `.bss` section), so attempt to call it (naturally) produces a `SIGSEGV`.

To fix this, either make these symbols `static`, or name them differently, e.g. `p_vkGetInstanceProcAddr` and `p_vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties`.

**Update:**

> Why compiling lib.c together with main.c directly (without an intermediate shared library inbetween) works?

Because symbols are (by default) not exported from an executable in the dynamic symbol table, *unless* some shared library references them.

You can change the default by adding `-Wl,--export-dynamic` (which causes the main executable to export all non-local symbols) to the main executable link line. If you do so, linking `lib.c` with `main.c` will also fail.

> Also how can vkGetInstanceProcAddr`"capture" the`vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties` in lib.so?

By using normal symbol resolution rules -- the first ELF binary to define the symbol wins.

> Shouldn't it just return some kind of predefined address that points to the correct function? I imagine that it is implemented with something like `if (!strcmp(...)) return vkGetInstanceProcAddr_internal`.

If it were implemented this way, it would have worked.

The implementation I can find doesn't do the `..._internal` part:

```
void *globalGetProcAddr(const char *name) {
    if (!name || name[0] != 'v' || name[1] != 'k') return NULL;

    name += 2;
    if (!strcmp(name, "CreateInstance")) return vkCreateInstance;
    if (!strcmp(name, "EnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties")) return vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties;
...
```

Arguably that is an implementation bug -- it should return the address of a local alias (the `..._internal` symbol) and be immune to symbol overriding.

Comment: Why compiling `lib.c` together with `main.c` directly (without an intermediate shared library inbetween) works? In that case, why `vkGetInstanceProcAddr` returns the correct address? Also how can `vkGetInstanceProcAddr` "capture" the `vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties`  in lib.so? Shouldn't it just return some kind of predefined address that points to the correct function? I imagine that it is implemented with something like `if (!strcmp(...)) return vkGetInstanceProcAddr_internal`

Comment: @JimMorrison I've updated the answer.